# Can't see assets in my IDE but they do exists in the container

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got an app written in Golang which I recently containerized.

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
##              Stage 1               ##
## ################################## ##
FROM golang:1.20-alpine AS builder

# Add Maintainer info
LABEL maintainer="Bob Belcher <bobbelcher@bobsburgers.com>"

# Install git.
# Git is required for fetching the dependencies.
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git

# We create an /app directory in which we'll put all of our project code
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# RUN go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@latest

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and the go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

# We want to build our application's binary executable
RUN cd /app/cmd && CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main ./...
#CMD ["air", "-c", ".air.toml"]

## ################################## ##
##              Stage 2               ##
## ################################## ##
# the lightweight scratch image we'll run our application within
FROM alpine:3.17.3 AS production

# We have to copy the output from our builder stage to our production stage
COPY --from=builder /app .

# we can then kick off our newly compiled binary exectuable!!
CMD ["./cmd/main"]
```

My `docker-compose.yml` is the following:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  championship-api:
    container_name: championship-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /app
    depends_on:
      # wait until the database is up and running, otherwise the app will try to establish connection
      # but the service won't be ready yet to receive any.
      championship-database:
        condition: service_healthy

    networks:
      - championship-net

  championship-database:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
#    container_name: championship-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    # using 3307 on the host machine to avoid collisions in case there's a local MySQL instance installed already.
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    # use variables declared in .env file
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      #MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abcd1234
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "exit | mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 30
    volumes:
      - championship-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - championship-net

# persisted storage
volumes:
  championship-db-data:

# networks
networks:
  championship-net:
    driver: bridge
```

When running the app is working as expected. So this app is an API, I've got an endpoint to upload images. When I upload an image the response returned is one of success, and the image is successfully uploaded indeed, but I cannot see it in my IDE under the directory they are supposed to be stored:

[image: IDE]

But if I get into the container `docker exec -it championship-api sh` and navigate to the location where the images are supposed to be located the images are indeed there:

[image: container]

What am I missing? how can I get them to be visible in my IDE?

I thought that I needed to perhaps create a volume in the container and linked it to the location (local) where the project exists in my computer, so I added this to the volumes list:
`- ./assets/media:/app/assets/media/`
now my api service looks like this:

```
championship-api:
    container_name: championship-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /app
      - ./assets/media:/app/assets/media/
    depends_on:
      # wait until the database is up and running, otherwise the app will try to establish connection
      # but the service won't be ready yet to receive any.
      championship-database:
        condition: service_healthy

    networks:
      - championship-net
```

but after building and running it again it is still behaving the same.

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Your image doesn't show /app, so are you sure you're mounting the volume correctly?

Comment: `./assets/media:/app/assets/media/` based on the screenshot from `docker exec` it appears that the data is being written into `/assets/media/...` (not `/app/assets...`)? [Also note](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#volumes) that "the relative path is resolved from the Compose file’s parent directory" (so I suspect you might need `../assets/media:/assets/media/` assuming your `docker-compose.yml` is in the `docker-compose` folder).

Comment: hey @OneCricketeer and @Brits, that was the issue indeed, mapping wasn't right, and as you both mentioned i didn't need `/app`. Thanks for your help. I'm curious about something: this is a personal app that eventually I'll push (for personal use) to either AWS or GCP, how does the mapping work once the container is pushed onto those services (I'm new in that regards)?

Comment: "AWS or GCP" offer volume services (e.g. [Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/efs-volumes.html)/[Google](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-network-file-systems)). However, you may want to consider storage accessed via the network (e.g. [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)/[Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs)) for media (try to keep containers [stateless and immutable](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-operating-containers#ensure_that_your_containers_are_stateless_and_immutable))

Comment: I agree. You'll want to rewrite the code to upload files to S3/GCS instead of local fs